# useMemo Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, react-usememo

First, I load a Redux-connected component using `React.lazy` and useMemo

```
const Component = useMemo(() => lazy(() => import('./Component')), []);
```

Then, I render it depending on my route with `BrowserRouter` like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Suspense fallback={<>Loading...</>}>
      <Route exact path='/' render={() => <SubscriptionList/> } />
    </Suspense>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I have multiple router that I want to lazy-load. I can't extract the "useMemo()" function, because I get warning:

```sh
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

What do I do wrong, what's the problem here?

Answer (score -1):

Lazy is enough to lazy load your components you don't need useMemo.

You can memoize your component like this.

export const MemoizedMovie = React.memo(Movie);

And if you are writing useMemo at top of your file it is wrong all the hooks should be called inside react component only.

Comment: It is enough to load, but it doesn't prevent rerender in some setups and with useMemo it does.

Comment: Can you upload full code or detailed code to see what's wrong!